# How do you make plus layout with a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**How can I make such a box (divs) layout with a flexbox (only flexbox)?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```css
.flex {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.col { 
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.el {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I offer a variant with a nested container **boxes_inside**, built vertically.

For indents, instead of margins, you can use the `gap` rule.

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 30px;
}

.boxes_inside {
  display: inherit;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 30px;
}

.box {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box"></div>

    <div class="boxes_inside">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is interesting too like the answer above, thank you!

Comment: @Lukas, Will you make these squares mobile responsive?

Comment: Yes, I'll need them to be responsive, I think the solution above (i broke down the logic behind it) will work better, what do you think?

Comment: @Lukas, In terms of specifics, the solutions are no different from each other. But only the solution above uses a margin for indentation, and in my solution gap. Mobile adaptive of these blocks can be implemented using some flex rules. And even, perhaps, without media queries.