# CSS layout - grid or flex

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to create this layout.
https://pasteboard.co/K1C5o3k.jpg

I tried to use display: grid but the spacing was strange. What would be the best solution? Use grid or flexbox? How do I achieve this spacing using grid or flexbox?

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="test-grid">
    <div class="card box1">some text</div>
    <div class="card box2">some text</div>
    <div class="card">some text</div>
    <div class="card box4">some text</div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrap {
  max-width: 600px;
}
.test-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}
.card {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 160px;
  min-height: 220px;
}
.box1 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.box4 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804045/how-do-you-make-plus-layout-with-a-flexbox/65804203#65804203

Comment: CSS Grid and Flexbox usually both get the job done, but are used in commonplace differently. Searching them up on caniuse.com usually links to useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your grid layout, I use grid-template-row/columns to define the fraction amount and then grid-template-areas to layout the elements, for each child element you want to define the unique class as its grid-area. You can use gap to control the spacing between the elements. Once you define a height and width for the parent element, the children will fill in their respective *fraction*, along with any defined gap.

Then use a media query with flex for your mobile layout. You may need to tweek the CSS a bit to get it to look just as you want, but the following example should do the trick.

```css
.test-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px 20px;
  grid-template-areas:
    ". two ." 
    "one two four" 
    "one three four" 
    ". three .";
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
 background-color: tomato;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .test-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test-grid">
  <div class="one box">some text</div>
  <div class="two box">some text</div>
  <div class="three box">some text</div>
  <div class="four box">some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Grid and flex will do the work, it just based on your preferences.

Snippet below will do the trick and when the screen became small (less than 500px). The grid will show as a list.

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 600px;
}
.test-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}
.card {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 160px;
  min-height: 220px;
}

.box1 {
    grid-column: 1/span 1;
    grid-row: 2/span 2;
}
.box2 {
  grid-column: 2/span 2;
    grid-row: 1/span 1;
}
.box3 {
  grid-column: 3/span 2;
    grid-row: 2/span 2;
}
.box4 {
  grid-column: 2/span 2;
    grid-row: 3/span 3;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .test-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="test-grid">
    <div class="card box1">box1</div>
    <div class="card box2">box2</div>
    <div class="card box3">box3</div>
    <div class="card box4">box4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using only grid. In this example we create many small grid rows (10px each) which then allows you to start each element at a specific row and adjust the boxes by 10 pixel increments.

```css
.test-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 160px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(45, 10px);
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.card {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 160px;
  min-height: 220px;
}
.box1 {
  grid-row-start: 10;
}
.box2 {
  grid-row-start: 0;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
.box3 {
  grid-row-start: 24;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
.box4 {
  grid-row-start: 8;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="test-grid">
    <div class="card box1">some text</div>
    <div class="card box2">some text</div>
    <div class="card box3">some text</div>
    <div class="card box4">some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```